define cause for Error in Mock When (MUnit)
I tried to define Error with typeID and cause for Mock When in MUnit
If I put cause as below shown, I got Exception as below, according to Excpetion.
I assume Cause Input is expectiong Expression instead of String, but i have no glue how to write Expression for Cause Input there
Any hints are welcome!
Define Cause for Error in Mock when

Exception in IDE
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.ConfigurationException: [rest_v1_service-orders-test-suite.xml:54]: A static value ('by http not found exception') was given for parameter 'cause' but it requires an expression
at org.mule.runtime.artifact.activation@4.6.7/org.mule.runtime.module.artifact.activation.internal.ast.validation.AstValidationUtils.logWarningsAndThrowIfContainsErrors(AstValidationUtils.java:55)


The error is likely to be in the code you have written, specifically near the 'by http not found exception' string that appears to be in your code. If you show what you currently have someone may be able to point out what you can do to fix your issue.

i guess Cause Input is expectiong Expression instead of String, but i have no glue how to write Expression for Cause

Perhaps you can figure out a way to rephrase your question so that it indicates that that specifically is the part you need help with. There may be multiple possible ways of trying to create an exception so to get help it might be smart to provide the actual relevant line of code.

The relevant documentation is here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/latest/mock-event-processor#parameters
It suggests inputting the following:
#[java!java::lang::Exception::new("This is the error message")]

The java! part indicates that the code that follows will be a Java-like expression. The java::lang:: is the namespace containing the Exception class.

thanks for the example. It got different exception say "Mocked event's error failure. The attributes typeId and cause are mutually exclusive. Please define only one of them [Not accessible. Value obtained from method: getDetailedDescription()]" . looks like we could only use either TypeId or Cause but not both

The documentations mentions it: If you create a mock error, choose one of the following parameters....
